# How to stop handlebars auto-compiler

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have the following code in nodejs 5.3.0:

```
require('handlebars');

var template = require('./template.hbs');

console.log(template());
```

And I see that handlebars auto-compile the template on require without calling the compile or anything.

How can I stop that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop it using

```
require.extensions['.handlebars'] = null;
require.extensions['.hbs'] = null;
```

After the handlebars require.